# Windows shortcut to directly open a new folder in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, shortcuts

Is there any key to directly open a new folder in the Windows Vista?
Unlike XP, Vista does not have any quicklaunch button on the side of the window.

Comment: What quick launch are you referring to? Do you mean the Windows Explorer sidebar?

Comment: this is unfair accepted answer !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While holding the Alt key, press in succession : F W F.

Comment: or right-click in empty-space and W,F.

Comment: @BlueNovember: Correct, but the OP specified a shortcut only.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ALT+ F +W+ F</kbd>   for the NT / 2000 / XP line, or +enter if you are in explorer

While on desktop or windows explorer press keys  <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> to create a new folder instantly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut key / button to create New Folder

1. Download [bxNew Folder utility](http://www.baxbex.com/files/bxnewfolder.exe)
2. Install the utility by following on-screen steps.
3. After install open Windows Explorer to see “New Folder” button.
4. You can click “New Folder” button or press F12 key to create new folder anywhere on your XP computer.

new-folder-windows-xp-dialog-box

[image]

[image]

[Source](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/create-new-folder-with-keyboard-shortcut-hotkey-in-windows-xp/) of this answer